# MySQL issue while creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my SQL code I am trying to solve

```
create table Sales_Order
(
    orderno varchar2(6) primary key check(orderno like 'O%'),
    clientno varchar(6),
    foreign key references Cust_Master(clientno),
    orderdate date not null,
    delytype char(1) check(delytype in ('P','F')) default 'F',
    billyn char(1),
    payment_mode varchar2(15)
    check(payment_mode in ('COD', 'Net Banking', 'Credit Card', 'Debit Card')),
    delydate date,
    orderstatus varchar2(10) 
    check(orderstatus in ('In Process', 'Fulfilled', 'BackOrder', 'Cancelled')
);
```

I am getting an error at line 1:

> ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Comment: That's an Oracle error, not a MySQL error. Are you sure this is MySQL?

Comment: In addition to what The Impaler said in his answer, do you want the `delytype` column to be `not null`? Neither the check constraint nor the default clause guarantee that the column will be `not null`; if you need it, you must say it explicitly in `create table`.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you are using is incorrect according to Oracle database. There are a few typos, a wrong syntax for a FK and wrong location of the `DEFAULT` clause. In short, you should use:

```
create table Sales_Order (
  orderno varchar2(6) primary key check(orderno like 'O%'),
  clientno varchar(6) references Cust_Master (clientno),
  orderdate date not null,
  delytype char(1) default 'F' check(delytype in ('P','F')),
  billyn char(1),
  payment_mode varchar2(15)
    check(payment_mode in ('COD', 'Net Banking', 'Credit Card', 'Debit Card')),
  delydate date,
  orderstatus varchar2(10) 
    check(orderstatus in ('In Process', 'Fulfilled', 'BackOrder', 'Cancelled'))
);
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ff4752a383d8cfddb7e6ad1f7edc4231).